# How is the expression True And -1 evaluated?

Tags: vb.net

How come the expression `True And -1` evaluates to `-1`?

I would expect that the second operand (i.e. `-1`) would be automatically converted to `True` and the result would be `True`.

I realize that `And` is interpreted here as the bit-wise AND-operator. But why would that be the case, when the first operand is boolean and the logic interpretation is possible?

Comment: Change to `Option Strict On` and don't care about strange conversions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how the [And Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx) is supposed to work. To quote from the documentation:

> If the operands consist of one **Boolean** expression and one numeric expression, Visual Basic converts the **Boolean** expression to a numeric value (–1 for **True** and 0 for **False**) and performs a bitwise operation.

Why does it do that? We can only speculate, but I suspect two reasons:

1. Backwards compatibility. VB6 and VBA also behave like this.
2. For logic operations, the new short-circuiting operators **AndAlso** and **OrElse** should be used instead. Thus, it makes sense that the legacy operators **And** and **Or** are used mainly for the bitwise operations.

Comment: Is it for the same reason that `"9"+5` is evaluated to `14` and not `"95"`? Is it because `&` is mainly used for concatenation, while `+` is mainly used for addition?

Comment: `"9"+5` evaluates to 14 *only* with `Option Strict` off!  (and in some cases can result in `"95"`)   @MeirGoldenberg

Comment: @Plutonix: I agree with the first, but not with the second part of your statement: The documentation explicitly states that `"9" + 5` will always yield `14` (Double), when Option Strict is Off: See the Remarks section of the [+ Operator documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2.aspx).

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, that is what I am talking about. So, what is the answer to the question?

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg: Only Microsoft can say for sure, but I guess it's a valid hypothesis.